# Implementing an auto-suggest feature (not auto-complete)

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack, autosuggest

I am using django haystack (with ElasticSearch search engine) and wants to implement an auto-suggest feature which is different from auto-complete.

For e.g. consider a small data set (table rows) that have been indexed:

```
When your code is all set
And you have finished it all
Your goals have been met
And you feel not so small
```

This is what I wish to implement:

```
First input query(for search index): 'finished coding'
expected search result:
    When your code is all set
    And you have finished it all

Second, input query(for search index): 'finished coding! goals met!'
expected search result:
    When your code is all set
    And you have finished it all
    Your goals have been met
```

haystack's `SearchQuerySet().autocomplete(content=above query)` doesn't produce the above result.

How to build such a queryset?

We also see it in stackoverflow's ask question page; i.e. when we type in the title field it gives us a list of **Questions that may already have your answer**.

Comment: `haystack's SearchQuerySet().autocomplete(content=above query) doesn't produce the above result.` What _does_ it produce?

Comment: @Hedde: It just matches sequentially for exact phrases; else returns an empty result!

Comment: Did you set haystack's [default operator](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v1.2.4/settings.html#haystack-default-operator) to 'OR', it defaults to 'AND'..

Comment: ok! set it to 'OR'. Now it matches the phrase( even though I jumbled it) but only if it's from single row. It return empty match when I query with words from different rows.

Answer (score 1):

I got expected results by using:

```
SearchQuerySet().filter(content__in=query.split())
```

Maybe it's not the correct way, as tokenizing is the task of the search engine but it worked for me.